# How to only allow access to a route if the current user's id matches the id in said route? NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route similar to this:

```
router.get("/users/:id/thing", middlewareObj.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    res.render("thing.ejs");
});
```

I want this route to only be accessible if the current user's id matches the ":id" in the route. How would I go about doing this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Rolling your own authentication is a big deal. Look into passport js. I think passport js local is what you want specifically. It checks if a user is authenticated before allowing access to a route, just as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the logged user (I am assuming you have it in req.user [indeed you should check on passport]) with the param ID:

```
if(req.user.id != req.params.id) return res.status(400);
```

You could remove the id from the URL and simply use the logged user data. Because if the url id matches the user id, you have something redundant. So, with this..

```
router.get("/users/thing", middlewareObj.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  let id = req.user.id;

  //do something with the ID which you assume you do, otherwise why you want the ID in the first place

  ...

  //return the view  
  res.render("thing.ejs");
});
```